# How to make DropDownListFor use item IDs instead of indices?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table with a dropdown list in each row, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Transactions[i].CategoryID, ...)
```

and everything mostly works. I can select items, submit the form, and the model has my updated selections. So far so good.

The problem is that this isn't very reliable. Since the name of each dropdown is based on an index rather than an ID that means the match-up between the post values and the actual items living in the database are based on indices. Most of the time that works fine, but what if the list of items changes between the time the page loads and the time a user does a postback? The indices have changed, which means the post data won't match up correctly, and bad things happen. OR I've seen the browser incorrectly try to preserve selections in dropdowns between posts, but because the list of items is changing (what may be item #2 now may be item #3 by the time the page is refreshed) and everything is based on indices, the wrong dropdowns get the wrong values.

So basically, how can I force the dropdowns to generate a name and ID that looks more like this:

```
Transactions_CategoryID_12385652 // 12385652 is the CategoryID
```

rather than this:

```
Transactions_4_CategoryID // 4 is the array index
```

and still have the benefits of automatic binding?

Edit: The second issue I mentioned (input values being restored incorrectly after a refresh) seems to only happen with Firefox. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46845

Comment: Short answer is no. And you would not what to even attempt to change the `name` attribute since it would mean model binding would fail. You need to include the models `id` property in the view so that `CategoryID` is matched up with its associated `ID` - `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Transactions[i].ID)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke The hidden field will help. It'll make sure I'm always updating the correct transaction even if the list of transactions changes (the 1st scenario I mentioned). But it still won't stop the browser from potentially mucking with the values in the dropdowns (the 2nd scenario).

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by _the browser from potentially mucking with the values in the dropdowns_?

Comment: Say you have a list of 2 transactions: "shirts" and "apples." The category dropdown for "shirts" has the name "Transactions_0_CategoryID" and the category dropdown for "apples" has the name "Transactions_1_CategoryID". The user selects "food" as the category for the "apples" transaction, but *doesn't* submit. Instead they do some kind of refresh, but after the refresh there are 3 items in the list: "shirts," "dogs," and "apples." The browser tries to preserve what the user selected in the "Transaction_1_CategoryID" dropdown, which means "dogs," not "apples," is now categorized as "food." Oops!

Comment: What? If you view is correct, then if your not initially setting the value of the property, then you should have a `Please select` option (generated using the `optionLabel` parameter of `DropDownListFor()` so that the default (`null` option) is selected. And if you are correctly setting the value based on editing an existing item, then that item will always be selected. I cant imagine what you must be doing if your seeing that kind of behavior

Comment: In any case, its the `value` of your property that determines what is selected, and it has nothing to do with the `name` attribute so its hard to understand how you think changing the name attribute could do anything (other that ensure model binding will fail)

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining it very well, so here's an example of what I mean: http://pastie.org/10821048 It shows the wrong dropdown getting the selected value of another dropdown. I can duplicate the behavior I was talking about on Firefox but not Chrome, so maybe it's browser specific.

Comment: Not really sure what your trying to explain in that image. It pure client side only and has nothing to do with how it will work in MVC when your refresh the page and call a server method (which **binds** to your model properties/values)

Comment: The user may not notice the dropdown values have changed from what they selected. In that example I selected "food" for "lettuce." But if I refresh, an item gets added, the browser restores the value in the wrong dropdown, and I submit the form to the server then the server thinks I selected "food" for "kitten," which is **NOT** what I selected. Sure, it's technically a client-side problem, but it's caused because of the way MVC generates names.

Comment: I give up. You clearly have no understanding of what is really happening.

Comment: I understand just fine. Am I still not explaining the problem? Anyway, in case anyone finds this, here's a relevant link to a discussion at Firefox's bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46845

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write your own custom model binder as well as a Html extension to generate the element names in this way, or you could generate the markup manually using Razor.

Is there a particular reason you want need to do it this way? You're almost always following the conventions of the framework unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the exact collection you want to the view and bind that to the DropDownFor html helper.

Say you have a Person.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to add a new person.  Create a view model.  Create a property in this view model of type SelectList.  This select list will hold the collection of the model you want to populate the dropdown list with.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SelectList MySelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say you want the drop down list to hold the Person's Id as the selected value and the Person's name as the text value.  You may want to create a second view model to represent that or use an anonymous object.  Let's call the collection myCollection.  And let's say that the collection is made up of objects that have two properties (and Id and Name property).  Now simply pass this view model with a value for MySelectList.

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel 
{
    MySelectList = new SelectList(myCollection, "Id", "Name")
};
```

In your razor view you can set up the @Html.DropDownListFor like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.MySelectList)
```

In order to pass a select value to the view for the dropdownlist simply use the SelectList constructor overload that allows this value to be passed:

```
new SelectList(myCollection, "Id", "Name", selectedValue)
```